# Bug in long titles pushing "Ask Question" off-screen

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

I was looking at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit?rq=1) earlier, and noticed that *another* bug has surfaced.

The picture says it best:

[image]

On questions which have large unbroken strings in their titles, Ask Question can be pushed off-screen.

I'm using Chrome 72.0.3626.119 with a screen resolution of 1920x1080

Comment: Thats not all that is wrong with titles: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380792/title-doesnt-wrap-around-ask-question-button

Comment: my profile is also weird because of that question : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif?tab=profile

Answer (score 19):

The class `ow-break-word` on the h1 title doesn't do anything since there is no maximum width set.

[image]

Alternatively, add `word-break: break-word` as well to work:

[image]

Comment: Someone complaining on it breaking the line in the "wrong" place in 3...2...1... :)

Comment: Two hours later... *silence*

Comment: That line is breaking in the wrong place :) jk, ofc.

Comment: `word-break: break-word` fails in Firefox for me but `word-break: break-all;` works.

Comment: @Scoots, noticed that as well. The only suggestion the editor gives is `break-all`. This however breaks at a random point in the title.

Comment: It's CSS. It's not meant to work cross-platform.